# Opening a linux-crashdump dump with crash?

Tags: linux, ubuntu-16.04, linux-kernel, server-crashes

So I've been trying to debug a weird intermittent kernel crash for a server running Ubuntu-Server 16.04, which has had me stumped for ages, and so I installed and setup `linux-crashdump` following the [Ubuntu wiki crash dump recipe](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/CrashdumpRecipe).

After waiting for the issue to rear its head again, `linux-crashdump` has done its thing and generated a crash dump, but now I can't figure out how to make any use of it!

The Ubuntu guide provides two methods for viewing them, either using `crash` or `apport-retrace`, but neither of these methods works as described.

`apport-retrace` simply returns:

```
ERROR: report file does not contain the required fields
```

Meanwhile for `crash`, I've downloaded the appropriate image with debug info using `apt-get install linux-image-$(uname -r)-dbgsym` as recommended, before running the following command:

```
crash /usr/lib/debug/boot/vmlinux-4.4.0-93-generic /var/crash/linux-image-4.4.0-93-generic-201709131146.crash
```

However this results in an error of:

```
crash: linux-image-4.4.0-93-generic-201709131146.crash: not a supported file format
```

What is the correct way to view `linux-crashdump` dumps now? Am I missing steps that aren't in the guide?

Answer (score 1):

So I figured it out; it seems that the actual meat of the crash dump isn't in the `.crash` file at all, but instead is inside a folder.

The relevant contents of my `/var/crash` folder therefore looks like this:

```
/var/crash/
    201709131146/
        dmesg.201709131146
        dump.201709131146
    linux-image-4.4.0-93-generic-201709131146.crash
```

So what I needed to run was:

```
crash /usr/lib/debug/boot/vmlinux-4.4.0-93-generic /var/crash/201709131146/dump.201709131146
```

This (eventually) gave me the a useful stack trace and other details about what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use apport-unpack. Then gdb and backtrace. There are good examples online about how to use apport-unpack.

Comment: I'm afraid I might need a bit more to go-on than that; I can use apport-unpack to expand the .crash file into separate files but that doesn't solve any of the problems of then loading them somehow so I can see what went wrong. All of the examples I've found so far are for debugging app crashes, not kernel crashes.

Comment: When you unpack there should be a file called CoreDump.  Then run the linux crash utility.  For example `crash /usr/lib/debug/boot/vmlinux-3.x.0-24 /var/crash/CoreDump`.